# i want to find total width of "li" using jquery. how can i get text width? How can i do it?

Tags: jquery

My Code is look like below.  First alert display "test li 0" and its width 1024. But 1024 width is incorrect. Actually it is around 50 px. I want the width of text "test li 0".
how can i get text width?

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var total = 0;
var i=0;

$('#menutop > span> li').each(function(index) {

//var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i).css('width');
var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i).width();
alert(tesi + ':' + $(this).text());
total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(tesi);
i=parseInt(i)+1;

});
alert(total);
});

<ul id="menutop">
    <span><li id="i_0" style="background-color:blue;"> test li 0 </li></span>
    <span><li id="i_1" style="background-color:blue; width:150px;"> test li 1 </li></span>
    <span><li id="i_2" style="background-color:blue; width:200px;"> test li 2 </li></span>
</ul>
```

---

Comment: `<span>` is illegal outside a `li`. I would remove those first

Comment: I have removed the span but it will give me same width.

Comment: And you are 1000% sure it's not 1024 pixels wide? Because the `li` element is usually `display: block` and takes up the whole screen's width.

Comment: In the first li i m not giving a width so it is consider 1024px. So, i want to calculate each li text width "test li 0". How can i do it?

Comment: put a `<span>` *inside* the li and measure that.

Comment: It is giveing me 29px width for all li. In the second li my text is "test li 1 test li 1" but it will give 29px. It is wrong.

Comment: i've tested this on jsfiddle and i didn't get 1024. which browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/8v5tL/

Answer (score 2):

As **Pekka** suggested, you can put span inside the li and use the algorithm below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var total = 0;
var i=0;

$('#menutop > li').each(function(index) {

//var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i).css('width');
var tesi = $(document.getElementById("i_"+i).firstChild).width();
alert(tesi + ':' + $(this).text());
total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(tesi);
i=parseInt(i)+1;

});
alert(total);
});

<ul id="menutop">
    <li id="i_0" style="background-color:blue;"><span> test li 0 </span></li>
    <li id="i_1" style="background-color:blue; width:150px;"><span> test li 1 </span></li>
    <li id="i_2" style="background-color:blue; width:200px;"><span> test li 2 </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no need to use `"#i_"+i` though. `this` will do

Comment: It is alert 1st and 2nd li width. After 2nd li width. It will give error.  :-                                                      uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/rnd/detect-screen-size/jquery.js :: anonymous :: line 12" data: no]

Comment: Tried this solution here: jsfiddle.net/Kkwxj and it worked properly

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the results you want, I think you should place your `span`s inside the `li`s:

```
<ul id="menutop">
    <li id="i_0" style="background-color:blue;"><span> test li 0 </span></li>
    <li id="i_1" style="background-color:blue; width:150px;"><span> test li 1 </span></li>
    <li id="i_2" style="background-color:blue; width:200px;"><span> test li 2 </span></li>
</ul>
```

And do this:

```
...
$('#menutop > li > span').each(function(index) {   //Note the order
   var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i+" span").width();  //Get span width instead of li's
   //... the same code
```

That's because li's will try to occupy all the width by default (that's why you got 1024), but spans don't, only occupy their contents width.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: There is no need to use `"#i_"+i` though. `this` will do

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code a little bit.

```
var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i).width();
```

to

```
var tesi = jQuery("#i_"+i).css("display", "inline").width();
jQuery("#i_"+i).css("display", "block");
```

It temporarily converts the current `<li>` to inline, calculates the width and then converts it back to block.